# pjsip call doesn't reach the opposite site right after termination

Tags: c++, pjsip, pjsua2

I've got simple SIP client written on C++ using pjsua2 library (guess almost the same as pjsip). The client is only used to make a call (not to answer any calls). The problem is in that I can't make a call to the opposite site after I terminate the call from the opposite site.
So the scenario is following:

1. I do the call from my SIP client
2. Call reaches the oppsoite site and communication is OK.
3. I terminate the call from the oppsite site, my client receives `DISCONNECTED` call state and after that my client is closed.
4. Right after that I'm trying to do another call from my SIP client but it doesn't reach the oppsite site.

I thought that the problem was in the way I terminate my SIP client, but not completely sure about this statement. I did tests with MicroSIP softphone and there everything was OK.
Here is my code:

```
#include <pjsua2.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace pj;

class SipCall : public pj::Call
{
   public:
     SipCall(pj::Account &acc, int call_id = PJSUA_INVALID_ID):Call(acc, call_id)
     {

     }

    ~SipCall() = default;

    virtual void onCallMediaState(pj::OnCallMediaStateParam &params) override
    {
         std::cout << "***** onCallMediaState *****" << std::endl;
         CallInfo callInfo = getInfo();
         for (unsigned int i = 0; i < callInfo.media.size(); i++)
         {
             if (callInfo.media[i].status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE)
             {
                pjsua_conf_connect(callInfo.media[i].audioConfSlot, 0);
                pjsua_conf_connect(0, callInfo.media[i].audioConfSlot);
             }
         }
     }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Endpoint ep;
ep.libCreate();

EpConfig ep_cfg;
ep_cfg.medConfig.noVad = true;
ep.libInit(ep_cfg);
TransportConfig tcfg;
tcfg.port = 0;
try
{
    ep.transportCreate(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP, tcfg);
}
catch (Error &err)
{
    std::cout << err.info() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
ep.codecSetPriority("pcma", PJMEDIA_CODEC_PRIO_NORMAL + 15);
ep.libStart();

std::cout << "*** PJSUA2 STARTED ***" << std::endl;

// Configure an AccountConfig
AccountConfig acfg;
acfg.idUri = "sip:account@domain";
acfg.regConfig.registrarUri = "sip:domain";
acfg.sipConfig.proxies = {"sip:domain;transport=tcp"};

AuthCredInfo cred("digest", "*", "username", 0, "password");
acfg.sipConfig.authCreds.push_back(cred);

Account *acc = new Account;
acc->create(acfg);

SipCall * call = new SipCall(*acc);

CallOpParam prm(true); // Use default call settings
call->makeCall("sip:dest@domain", prm);

while(call->isActive())
{

}

delete call;
printf("INFO: call deleted\n");
acc->shutdown();
delete acc;
printf("INFO: Acc deleted\n");

ep.libDestroy();

printf("INFO: ep lib destroyed.\n"); 
return 0;
}
```

As I read from the documentation, default keepalive interval is 15 second which should be ok. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?